# What is the size of the largest subset of the numbers 1 to n such that no number is twice as large as any other?

Tags: number-theory, extremal-combinatorics

Also, what is the size of the smallest subset of the numbers from 1 to n such that all the remaining numbers are either twice as great as or half as great as some number in the subset?

I believe that the answer to the first question may be two thirds n plus or minus 1.

This is how I arrived at 2n/3. Let S be a set of numbers such that no number is S is twice as great as any other number in S.
All numbers can be expressed as 2<sup>k</sup>o where o is an odd number. If 2<sup>k</sup>o is in S then 2<sup>k-1</sup>o and 2<sup>k+1</sup>o must be excluded from S.  It follows that for each o, the best we can do is to include half the numbers 2<sup>k</sup>o. Using n=100 as an example, the following procedure can be used.

Start by including the upper half of the set of numbers from 1 to 100.  This gives us the numbers from 51 to 100 to be placed in S. For each odd number o from 1 to 100, there is a number y in the numbers from 51 to 100 where y = 2<sup>k</sup>o and k is the maximum exponent such that the number does not exceed 100.  Next consider all numbers x such that 2x goes from 51 to 100.  This gives us 26 to 50, about a quarter of the numbers from 1 to 100, to be excluded from S.  Now consider all the numbers that are half the numbers from 26 to 50, 13 to 25, about an eighth of the numbers from 1 to 100. Twice the value of these numbers maps to the excluded numbers 26 to 50, so we can include the numbers 13 to 25.  Similarly, we must exclude the numbers from 7 to 12 and can include the numbers from 4 to 6

I hope it is clear that continuing this procedure and generalizing to all n, the number of entries included in S is (n/2 + n/8 + n/32 +...) = 2n/3.  There will of course be rounding errors, but this should be a good approximation for large n.  What I found by looking at specific cases is that it is an extremely good approximation even for relatively small n. I have not found a case where it was off by more than 1.

It is not difficult to find an algorithm to generate what seems to be a minimal set S for a number n such that no number is twice any other.  The basic idea is that if we include a number 2<sup>k</sup>o, we would like to include 2<sup>k+3</sup>o. This forces the exclusion of 2<sup>k+1</sup>o and 2<sup>k+2</sup>o.   I wrote a program to do this and I am generating sets of size about .571 times n.

Finally, the first problem can be generalized in an obvious way to find the largest subset S of numbers from 1 to n such that no number in S is c times greater than any other number in S.  We note that any number can be expressed as c<sup>k</sup>x, where x is not divisible by c. For each x, we again want half of the values c<sup>k</sup>x. If you are willing to accept the previous 2/3 estimate, in an analogous fashion we get c/(c+1) for the general case.  To see how we get the formula, instead of starting with numbers > n/2, we now start by placing into S numbers > n/c, of which there are n(1-1/c)=n(c-1)/c.  We now alternately exclude and include subsets whose size is 1/c times the size of the previous inclusion/exclusion group. We end up with a total of n(c-1)/c times the geometric series in $1/c^2$, which simplifies to nc/(c+1).

Comment: [OEIS A050292](https://oeis.org/A050292)

Comment: Let me encourage user1153980 to have a look at that OEIS page and then post a summary as an answer here.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the OEIS page.  I had not heard of them before.  Unfortunately,  I can;t follow what it is that they are saying.  

I could explain the logic of my two thirds n estimate.  With the aid of a computer program, I tested it for several values of n, and so far have not been off by more than 1.

Comment: If you want to be sure that Rob sees your comment, you have to put @Rob in it.

Comment: The second sequence appears to be [OEIS A123087](https://oeis.org/A123087).

Comment: Re the first question: Instead of going from the top down, you can build from the bottom up: $1,3,4,5,7,9,11,12,13,15,16,17,19,20,\dots$ I haven't tried to find a formula for that approach, but (within any error of computation by hand) I get $67$ out of the first $100$, in agreement with the top down method.

Comment: The asymptotic result $c/(c+1)$ is mentioned in [this link from OEIS](https://oeis.org/FinchTriple.html).

Comment: @RobPratt The $0.571$ in the question looks reasonable to me for the smallest subset: I get $6$ for $n=10$; $57$ for $n=100$; $572$ for $n=1000$; $5714$ for $n=10000$; $57143$ for $n=100000$; and $571429$ for $n=1000000$;

Comment: I found a way of deriving the .571 and, like the 2/3 estimate, it works a whole lot better than it seems that is should.  If, in the 2/3 derivation, 1/4 is replaced by 1/8 then you get .5 times a geometric series in 1/8, giving 4/7.